# Choosing the right databases server for ios apps

Tags: ios, database

I am developing my first IOS apps that will require users to register with profile details and profile pic. 
The apps will do some computation finding similarities among the users and display them for the users.
As such, I will need a database server to store individual's registeration details and profile pic.

I have looked at AWS, google app engine and parse and remain undecided. 
AWS seems pretty scary with the confusing pricing computation.
Google app engine looks pretty difficult to implement.
Parse doesn't seem economically friendly as well.

As such, i will like to seek for advice in choosing e database based on
1) suitability to my app
2) low pricing
3) able to scale up to handle heavy traffic

Some advices will be greatly appreciated!

Spen

Comment: i too have similar requirement and confused which to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way is using webservice. So, you can have your MSSQL, MySql etc databases on the server side then you should implement webservices to reach DB tables.

Second, you can use some api's such as parse.com which will give you 1.000.000 requests per month. Parse.com api is very easy to use.

Third is SQL lite.

In your case I think the best option is using webservices.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web service, but that require some skills others than iOS development. It's more complicated and time-consuming than other ways, but once you've got your server you are free to do almost everything.

You can also use a backend provider. There are a lot of them for iOS apps, and each of them have some specificities. This article can help you choosing a backend provider :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more?preview=true

I personally use Parse.com for the free plan, and because of the Facebook integration (Parse was acquired with Facebook), which makes it easy to use for social apps. The downside is you only have one GB of free space available, but if you need it only to save a profile picture, it will be good enough until your app reach a certain popularity. The website is full of examples and samples projects, which make Parse.com easy to use in my case. (I'm not affiliated with Parse.com in any way.)

The choice is fully yours, and depends on your time/skills/money/insertOthersArgumentsHere.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon Web Services is an Infrastructure-as-a-service (IaaS)**. So it is very low level. You need to create a backend from scratch using Rails, Nodejs, PHP, or whatever. But you need to configure your database, monitor the servers, etc.

**Google App engine is a Platform-as-a-service (PaaS)** so you don't have to worry about the infrastructure, but all the backend stuff is still very manual. You need to create a web service from scratch in order to communicate your iOS application with the backend.

**Parse is a Mobile-backbend-as-a-service (MBaaS)** so you don't have to worry about the backend stuff and additionally you have an SDK to start making queries and anything else from your mobile app.

**I work at [Backbeam](http://backbeam.io). It is a Backend as a service as well as a platform as a service**. You can do web and mobile apps and you can develop the business logic on the mobile app or on the server-side (so you can reuse it if you are developing for more than one platform). The paid plan starts at $29/month (unlike Parse that starts at $299). If you want further information we will be glad to assist you.